# using gspread with GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I am looking for a way to access google sheets in datalabs using gspread (or any alternative) without hard-coding the credentials required such as in the popular solution online. It seems like some people have been successful with get_application_default() instead of the .JSON credentials.

I have been previously successful in accessing my google sheets stored in drive using the .JSON method specified [here][1], but have been unable to do the same with get_application_default().

This is what I have:

```
    import gspread
    oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    credentials = credentials.create_scoped(['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'])
    gs = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    gs.login()
    sheet = gs.open('name of my google sheet')
```

Unfortunately the error I get is as follows:

```
    (401, '401: <HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</H1>\n<H2>Error 401</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n')
```

It seems like the error is quite generic as I've seen it plastered all over the web- with none of the solutions working.

Here is my code that works using a direct path to my credentials (essentially hard-coding a password):

```
    def GspreadAuthorization(credential_path):    
      try:
        import oauth2client
      except ImportError:
        !pip install oauth2client --no-deps -q
        import oauth2client
      scopes =  ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://docs.google.com/feeds']
      if isfile(credential_path):    
        if int(oauth2client.__version__[0:1]) == 1:
          from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
          json_key = json.load(open(credential_path))
          credentials = 
    SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], 
    json_key['private_key'], scopes)
        elif int(oauth2client.__version__[0:1]) >= 2:
          from oauth2client.service_account import 
    ServiceAccountCredentials
          credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credential_path, scopes)
        else:
          print 'The Version of oauth2client is not available ~~~'
        return gspread.authorize(credentials)
      else: 
        raise Exception('Service Account Credential json file can not be found! Please do the following steps, \n \
        1. Create the credential file from project IAM & Admin page and put it under folder /Automotive/Framework; \n \
        2. Rename the credential file as "gspread-api_service_account.json".')
```

Help would be super appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: your token does not have access privileges to access google spread sheets

Comment: How come it does while I use the .JSON method? Is this something I need to configure on the google project account that I'm using?

Comment: the error you are facing says Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope so yes, its something do to with the project configuration and it's a bit hard to guess what has gone wrong without seeing the configurations

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/295

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, however that link only answers issues with the direct .JSON credentials included. With the same project, I had no problem accessing google sheets with the .JSON method described in that post, which makes me think the project's config is fine (all API's enabled). ThePlummie's comment regarding using GoogleCredentials.get_application_default() instead of a .JSON file is essentially the same as mine, and hasn't been answered yet. Any help regarding that specific issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cannot give more inputs without seeing the big picture sorry about it